# Bash If Else for login -p

Tags: bash, if-statement, solaris

the command logins -p is to show which users do not have a password while wc -l is to count the number of newlines. Thus, logins -p | wc -l shows the number of users that do not have a password. In my case, logins -p | wc  -l returns me a value of 4 but when I compare it to be equal to 0, it prints "equal to 0" which is wrong. I would like to ask if there are any mistakes in my script and does wc -l returns an INT? Thanks.

```
if [ "$(logins -p | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "equal to 0"
else 
  echo "not equal to 0"
fi
```

Comment: Put a `set -x` at the top of your script (after any shebang line of course) and run it again. The the standard `bash` debugging tool.

Comment: `echo "$(logins -p | wc -l)"`

Comment: It's alright, thanks. I added backticks it worked.